# External User as SharePoint Administrator

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, external-users, guest-access

We have added a new guest account and granted him the SharePoint administrator role.

But when the user try to access the SharePoint online admin site, the user will get that external sharing is disabled, as follows:-

[image]

So the question is:

Can we add external user as SharePoint administrator inside our office 365 tenant?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to this Microsoft [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-admin-role),

> Global admins, SharePoint admins, and site admins all need to be
> assigned a SharePoint license.

In my point of view, for safety consideration, external user cannot be global administrator.

Comment: i do not want them to be global admins, i want them to be sharepoint admins

Comment: Even if the SharePoint admin, the user need to be assigned a SharePoint license.

Answer (score -1):

Well, obviously, this is not best practice... But have you checked the external sharing settings of the tenant ?
There are multiple external sharing levels, like on a list item, on a site collection and, lastly, on the tenant.

The external sharing settings are best described in the below link:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off#change-the-organization-level-external-sharing-setting

You should also keep in mind that a user that has access to SharePoint, must be assigned a o365 license (even the lowest like F1).

I will try to stress out again that this is not best practice and external users are not meant to be tenant administrators.

Comment: best practices are meant to be according to the requirement...  my question is about technical capability to share the SharePoint online site admin with external user... is this technically possible?

Comment: i tried mendling with the settings of the external sharing in the Org level, and i think it's not doable, since these settings refer only to content within sharepoint and not administrative access. I don't believe that you will ever be able to give administrative access to an account that is handled within a different AAD or Directory in general